# Proj4js: How to convert from ED50 to WSG84?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geojson, proj4js

I tried the below

(I used `+proj=longlat +ellps=intl +no_defs` for **ED50**, maybe that's the mistake)

```
proj4(new proj4.Proj('+proj=longlat +ellps=intl +no_defs'),
 new proj4.Proj('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84'),
 [669257.722015602, 3556445.24116905]);
```

But I got bad result `([79.34262031843741, 0])`

The desired result is `[34.793890 , 32.130109]`.